# how to hide total from admin-new-order.php woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to keep only Tax,Subtotal and Payment method on footer admin mail woocommerce, without TOTAL.
A litle help please!

I want to echo $total without tax only for admin email order.
I find only to not echo total from email-order-items.php

Before removing :

```html
<tfoot>
  <?php
   if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
     $i++;
     ?><tr>
      <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:left; <?php if ( $i === 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
      <td class="td" style="text-align:left; <?php if ( $i === 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
     </tr><?php
    }
   }
  ?>
 </tfoot>
```

And after:

```html
<tfoot>
</tfoot>
```

But this solution does not help because it deletes total of all mails.

I mention that the price of my products are displayed with taxes and without taxes like this: [Suffix for price display:

{price_including_tax} 
Displays the total tax: Detailed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtM1l.jpg)

Comment: Can you clarify? Also what have you tried? Showing more effort will probably help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Please copy you woocommerce emails template folder from woocommerce plugin and create a folder in your current theme woocommerce  after that copy emails folder in it. After tha you can remove or customize admin email content.

Copy from woocommerce plugin  Woocommerce > templates > emails > admin-new-order.php

Create folder and paste it to Current Theme Folder> Woocommerce > emails > admin-new-order.php

Comment: Yes, i have admin-new-order.php , email-order-details.php and email-order-items.php in my child thme >  Woocommerce > templates > emails. I need to echo Total without taxes only for admin new order. I find only to not echo total if i leave empty <tfooter> </tfooter>

Comment: Before removing <tfooter>: